# Display data from mongodb to html page in realtime

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb

I'm working on a python project, and I want to fetch and display data from mongodb in real-time, for example, display the new data in an html table page as soon as it's pushed to the DB, and the other data will be displayed while refreshing the page. Any help is highly appreciated.

this is my view.py :

```
def datatable_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = Scraping(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject=form.cleaned_data['subject']
            #run python code of scraping
            scrap(subject)
            #add the products scraped to the database
            client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
            # use variable names for db and collection reference
            db= client["db2"]
            col = db[subject]
            products = col.find()
            context = {'products' : products}
            #open datatable html and display all the data from database
            return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
    return
```

this is my html table page datatable.html :

```
<table id="scrap" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
 <tbody>
                {% for product in products %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ product.Title }} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Price }} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Currency }} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Stars }} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Orders}} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Shipcost }} </td>
                    <td> {{ product.Supplier }} </td>
                    <td><a href="{{product.Productlinks }}"> Click here</a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: It's too broad and opinion based for most parts, especially clientside. Topics to explore https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/ for Python to subscribe to updates, https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for Python to push updates to javascript. For the later, you may find some ready-to-use libraries that implement pub/sub on top of websockets transport.

Comment: I understand, but how can I do that with my current code, I don't know how to integer websockets in my code

Comment: It's not a single line but a piece of functionality spread between mongodb, python and javascript. You either learn how to write it, or hire somebody to do it for you.  As I said it's too broad for Stackoverflow format

Answer (score 0):

`col.find()` returns pymongo.cursor.Cursor object.

To fix the problem, you need to cast the cursor to the list: `list(products)`.

And return list of dict.